# Submit form isn't working on mobile but does on desktop

Tags: html, css, forms, laravel, responsive

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/submit']) !!}
      <label>Choose a subject
        <select name="subject">
            <option disabled selected value> -- select a subject-- 
            </option>
            <option value="mentalhealth">Mental Health</option>
            <option value="pyschology">Psychology</option>
            <option value="general">General Enquiry</option>
            <option value="personal">Personal</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Email
          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="To be 
          anonymous, just leave this blank (however we will not be able 
          to reply to your submission)." class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 
          col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      </label>
        <label class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Your 
          message to us
          <textarea placeholder="What would you like to ask or tell 
          us?" name="body" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-
          12"></textarea>
        </label>
        <section class="col-lg-12">
          <input class="btn btn-success" id="submitbutton" 
          type="submit" value="Send">
      </section>
{!! Form::close() !!}

input {
  border: solid 2px #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  resize: none;
}
```

Here is my form (im using laravel btw) to see the problem for yourself to http://www.seetheuniverse.co.uk/submit and try to use the form on desktop and mobile.

on mobile is just doesn't let you click in the input boxes at all but on a desktop it does. I've tried it using inspect element and my actual phone and it just doesn't work and I am really confused and wondered if everyone could help me out?

Comment: `col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12` is your problem. They are made to be used with a div http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete

Comment: Above comment is correct btw remove col-xs-12 and it works on mobile.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me